# Loop within a loop appears to overwrite all results with the final result

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops

I'm trying to loop through an array of months within an array of 'years' so I can calculate a count for each month using a custom angular filter. Below, In the first single while loop I create the structure I'm going to loop through.

```
while(i < itemYears.length) {
                //chuck the null end date. push the year part of the other end dates with months array.
                if (itemYears[i].end !== undefined && itemYears[i].end !== null) {
                    completeByMonth.push({ year: itemYears[i].end.substring(0,4), months: months });
                }
                i++; //increment
            }
```

Structure the above loop creates:

```
 {
  year: 2015,
  months: [
   { number: '01', text: 'January', count: 0 }
    ...
    ...
  ]
}
```

In the while within while loop, I loop through the each month of each item.

```
        //iterate throught the years
        while(j < completeByMonth.length) {
            var year = completeByMonth[j], k = 0;
            //iterate through the months for year.
            while(k < year.months.length) {
                year.months[k].count = $filter('endedMonth')(items, year.year, year.months[k].number).length; //filter items on year and month.
                console.log(year.year, year.months[k].text, 'count', year.months[k].count);
                k++; //increment
            }
            console.log(year);
            j++; //increment
        }

        console.log('completeByMonth', completeByMonth);
        return completeByMonth;
```

When I run it the console.logs they output the correct counts for each month of each year, except when the final completeByMonth array is printed every year has the same month counts as the final year in the array.

Question: 
How do I stop this.. overwriting of the month counts?

Any help, even an entirely different way of doing it, would be appreciated.

Comment: `var year = completeByMonth[j]` seems to be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So problem solved. I simply go rid of the 2 step process of:

1. create the object.
2. calculate the counts.

Now I calculate the counts during object creation and get the correct results for all years. The code doesn't look nice, but at least it works.

```
while(i--) {
            //chuck the null end date. push the year part of the other end dates with months array.
            if (itemYears[i].end !== undefined && itemYears[i].end !== null) {
                completeByMonth.push({ year: itemYears[i].end.substring(0,4),
                                      months: [
            { number: '01', text: 'January', count: $filter('endedMonth')(items, itemYears[i].end.substring(0,4), '01').length  },
            { number: '02', text: 'February', count: $filter('endedMonth')(items, itemYears[i].end.substring(0,4), '02').length },
            { number: '03', text: 'March', count: $filter('endedMonth')(items, itemYears[i].end.substring(0,4), '03').length },
            { number: '04', text: 'April', count: $filter('endedMonth')(items, itemYears[i].end.substring(0,4), '04').length },
            { number: '05', text: 'May', count: $filter('endedMonth')(items, itemYears[i].end.substring(0,4), '05').length },
            { number: '06', text: 'June', count: $filter('endedMonth')(items, itemYears[i].end.substring(0,4), '06').length },
            { number: '07', text: 'July', count: $filter('endedMonth')(items, itemYears[i].end.substring(0,4), '07').length },
            { number: '08', text: 'August', count: $filter('endedMonth')(items, itemYears[i].end.substring(0,4), '08').length },
            { number: '09', text: 'September', count: $filter('endedMonth')(items, itemYears[i].end.substring(0,4), '09').length },
            { number: '10', text: 'October', count: $filter('endedMonth')(items, itemYears[i].end.substring(0,4), '10').length },
            { number: '11', text: 'November', count: $filter('endedMonth')(items, itemYears[i].end.substring(0,4), '11').length },
            { number: '12', text: 'December', count: $filter('endedMonth')(items, itemYears[i].end.substring(0,4), '12').length }
        ] });
            }
        }
```

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what the filter is supposed to be doing.  But since we are in angular, I have rewritten your code to use forEach, and replaced the filter with an example count.

To me this code is more readable, and I hope it solves your issue.

```
var i = 0;
angular.forEach(completeByMonth, function(year){
    angular.forEach(year.months, function(month){
        i++;
        month.count = i;  
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15162/

Comment: Doesn't seems to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    while(j < completeByMonth.length) {
        var year = completeByMonth[j], k = 0;
        //iterate through the months for year.
        while(k < year.months.length) {
          (function(month, currentYear){
            currentYear.months[month].count = $filter('endedMonth')(items, currentYear.year, currentYear.months[month].number).length; //filter items on year and month.
            console.log(currentYear.year, currentYear.months[month].text, 'count', currentYear.months[month].count);
          )(k, year);
          k++; //increment
        }
        console.log(year);
        j++; //increment
    }

    console.log('completeByMonth', completeByMonth);
    return completeByMonth;
```

Your issue isn't related to Angular, but to how javascript (and their variables work). You can learn more about the issue at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures (section "Creating closures in loops: A common mistake").

Comment: Attempted, but no success.